# What is the |>> symbol in Scala

Tags: scala

Ran into a piece of code that looks like the following:

```
 chatRoom ? (Join("Robot")) map {
      case Connected(robotChannel) => 
        // Apply this Enumerator on the logger.
        robotChannel |>> loggerIteratee
    }
```

This comes from a sample Play Framework app. No idea what `|>>` is in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [an alias for `apply`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator) on [enumerators](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Enumerators). Essentially what it's doing is attaching a data source (the channel, an enumerator here) to a data sink (the logger, which is an iteratee).

Iteratees can be a little tricky to wrap your head around at first, but there's [a good introduction](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Iteratees) on the Play site.